# let $A$ be any inductive set, then $\{C \in P(A)|C \text{ is inductive set} \}$ is a set? ... and $\mathbb{N}$...?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

let $A$ be any inductive set, then $\{C \in P(A)|C \text{ is inductive set} \}$ is a set?

if $\{C \in P(A)|C \text{ is inductive set} \}$ is a set I can defined $\mathbb{N}:=\bigcap\{C \in P(A)|C \text{ is inductive set} \}$??

Thanks in advance!!

P.S.=$P(A)$ is power of (A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\mathscr{I}=\{C\in\wp(A):C\text{ is an inductive set}\}$ is a set: $\wp(A)$ is a set by the power set axiom, and $\mathscr{I}$ is then a set by the axiom schema of comprehension (or separation, or specification). (Of course this requires verifying that ‘$x\text{ is an inductive set}$’ can be expressed as a formula in the language of set theory, but that’s [straightforward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity#Alternative_method).)

You can then form $M=\bigcap\mathscr{I}$. (Since $A\in\mathscr{I}$, it’s clear that $M\subseteq A$.) To finish the argument, you’ll need to show that $M$ is inductive, and that if $I$ is any inductive set, then $M\subseteq I$. The first of these is completely straightforward. For the second, show that $I\cap A$ is inductive.

Comment: M.Scott... thanks soo much!! :)

Comment: You should probably argue that $\mathscr I$ is non-empty, otherwise $\forall x(x\in\bigcap\mathscr I)$.

Comment: @Soviet: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Asaf: I thought it pretty evident, but it can’t hurt to make it explicit.

Comment: @Brian: Unless the implicit mafia comes in and breaks your legs for going explicit... :-P

Comment: @Asaf: I thought that was the censors ...

Comment: They are working together. Just not on your legs. Only the Imp. Mafia works on your legs...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, but in this case is better to write $\mathbb{N}_A:=\{C \in \mathcal{P}(A)|C \text{ is inductive} \}$?? is true that if $B,D$ are two inductive sets then $\mathbb{N}_B=\mathbb{N}_D$.. is correct?

Comment: @Soviet: Once you prove that $M\subseteq I$ for **every** inductive set $I$, it follows that $\Bbb N_A=\Bbb N$.

Comment: okok Thanks! :)

Comment: @Soviet: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We can write a formula $\varphi(x)$ which states that $x$ is an inductive set. The power set axiom assures us that $\mathcal P(A)$ is a set, and so the separation schema assures us that the inductive subsets of $A$ is also a set.

Finally, note that $\bigcap\{\ldots\}$ is not intrinsic to the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ (rather the union is), so you just need to assure that the set you are intersecting is not empty. However since $A$ is inductive, it is not empty, and we're good.