# proof by contradiction: $B\triangleq\mathbb{N}_A$, then $B$ is unique!!

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

--- let $A$ be any inductive set, and $B$ a set, $B\triangleq \mathbb{N}_A$ if $B=\bigcap\{C \in \mathcal{P}(A)|C \text{ is inductive} \}$, then $B$ is unique

proof by contradiction: I suppose exists a $D\triangleq\mathbb{N}_A$ and $D \neq B$, but if $D \neq B$ then $D \nsubseteq B$ or $B \nsubseteq D$:

if $D \nsubseteq B$ then $\exists x \in D(x \notin B)$, if $x \in D \to x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \wedge x$ is inductive but also $x \notin B \to x \notin \mathcal{P}(A) \wedge x$ is not inductive.. but it is contraddittory..

if $B \nsubseteq D$.. the proof is similar... it is contraddittory

therefore I can't suppose exists a $D\triangleq\mathbb{N}_A$ and $D \neq B$ so $B\triangleq\mathbb{N}_A$ is unique!!

Is correct??

Thanks in advance!!

P.S.=[$\bigcap\{C \in \mathcal{P}(A)|C \text{ is inductive}$ is a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470789/let-a-be-any-inductive-set-then-c-in-pac-text-is-inductive-set)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a unary property $P$ (expressible as a formula in the language of set theory) and a set $y$, the [axiom schema of specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) tells you that  $\{x\in y\colon P(x)\}$ is a set. 
This assures the existence of the set $\Bbb N_A$ (after some details are observed).

**Remark:** The set $\{x\in y\colon P(x)\}$ is unique, i.e., $\forall u\forall v\color{blue}(\forall x\color{red}(\color{green}{x\in u \leftrightarrow (x\in y\land P(x))} \text{ and } \color{green}{x\in v\leftrightarrow (x\in y\land P(x))}\color{red})\rightarrow u=v\color{blue})$.
*Proof:* It's a direct consequence of the [axiom of extensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). $_\square$

You should be able to apply the above to your particular case.

The hardest thing here is to formalize what 'the set $z$ is unique' means, once that's done, everything is straightforward.

Comment: okok thanks soo much!! :)

Comment: @Soviet No problem. Let me suggest, however, that you're not to quick in accepting answers. Especially since there are a few set theorists here who might provide what you might feel like is a better answer. It's your choice, though.